# matlab tcpip server automatic stop after receive data

Tags: matlab, tcp, server

for example:

```
obj1 = tcpip('127.0.0.1', 8001, 'NetworkRole', 'server');
s.BytesAvailableFcn = @Callback;
fopen(obj1);
```

the matlab will exit Busy state after Callback function been called, and the server(obj1) no longer running.
how to make the server continuously run?

Answer (score -1):

```
set(obj1, 'ReadAsyncMode', 'continuous');
```

https://lost-contact.mit.edu/afs/cs.stanford.edu/package/matlab-r2009b/matlab/r2009b/toolbox/instrument/instrumentdemos/html/tcpip_demot_async.html